# How does accessing class variables from an instance work in python? - a confusing example

Tags: python

I have a very basic question about accessing class variables.

I thought I can reference class variables in a member function using the self keyword or the class name.

The code block below works along with my understanding

```
class Coo(object):
    num = 1

    def foo(self):    
        print self.num
        print Coo.num

coo = Coo()
coo.foo()

Output:
1
1
```

The confusion starts with below example

```
class Coo(object):
    num = 1

def foo(self):
    self.num = 2
    Coo.num = 3    
    print self.num
    print Coo.num

coo = Coo()
coo.foo()

Output:
2
3
```

The second example shows that accessing class variable using self or class name are different.

What would be the right way to access class variables in a member function?

Comment: There is an important distinction between class and instance attributes. Class attributes are shared by all members of that class, defined with `num=1`, which is different from an instance attribute, which is only set for that instance of the class, defined with `self.num = 1`. TLDR: self sets instance variables, not using it sets class variables.

Comment: If you see the first example, self.num is clearly referencing the class variable.

Comment: I think it just looks up num in its namespace and finds the class variable

Comment: Okay I think I have an idea what's going on

Comment: coming from c++ background, this seems to be ambiguity that makes me really wanting to find out the bottom of it.

Comment: There are two dicts in this case, the __dict__ of Coo and the __dict__ of an instance of Coo. __dict__ of Coo contains class attrs, __dict__ of the instance contains instance attrs. So self.num tries to look up in the instance dict, and then if its not found it goes into the Coo dict to find num

Comment: Please help me out of this misery.  This drives me crazy

Comment: So add some print statements `print(self.__dict__)` and `print(Coo.__dict__)`, you can see how the variables are stored seperately. When there isn't an instance attribute `self` looks into `Coo.__dict__` instead of `instance.__dict__`

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I think it makes sense.  However, I am still wondering if that is the official specification or loosely defined corner.

Comment: However, I would like to suggest moving your explanation to the answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: It's not an official explanation that's just my theory. I'd wait until someone who really knows python inside out to answer it. If in two days this still isn't answered remind me to place a bounty on it.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your help.  However, Printing dict really clarifies what notation would be proper since it shows what maps where.  I think your answer really clarifies my initial question - "what would be the right way?".

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you meant by proper, but if my comments inspired you to think up of a solution I suggest you self-answer your question :). I would like to look into backend of `self` before I answer anything.

Comment: I found the source of my confusion.   I assumed self.class_var_name notation from this example https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables.  This instance_name.class_variable notation confused me.

Comment: Alright I did some research and I have an answer! I hope it clears things up further :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python everything is an object, even classes themselves.

What:

```
class Coo(object):
    num = 1

    def foo(self):    
        print self.num
        print Coo.num
```

does is that it creates a class object with the name Coo. It has attributes foo and num, with num being an int and foo being a function object.

```
coo = Coo()
```

Creates an instance object of Coo() that has the name coo. The instance coo contains no attributes:

```
print(coo.__dict__)
>>>{}
```

However, since you can do `coo.foo()`, or `coo.num`, coo clearly has attributes. The way coo gets the ability to use attributes from `Coo` is how python's attribute lookup works.

For example when doing `coo.num`, python attempts to look up `num` inside of `coo.__dict__`, but since it cannot find num, it moves into `Coo.__dict__`, and finds entry `{num:10}`

The same thing happens when you try to call `coo.foo()`, `coo.__dict__` has no entry for `foo`, but `Coo.__dict__` does. `coo.foo()` essentially becomes `Coo.foo(coo)`, where the instance is passed in as `self`. This phenomenon is what lets instances of classes use their class functions! They look it up inside of their class's `__dict__`!

To use this to explain the anomaly in your question:

```
class Coo(object):
    num = 1

    def foo(self):    
        print self.num
        print Coo.num

coo = Coo()
coo.foo()
```

`coo` has no `num` attribute, so `num` is looked up inside `Coo` and they both print 10.

```
class Coo(object):
    num = 1

    def foo(self):
        self.num = 2
        Coo.num = 3    
        print self.num
        print Coo.num
coo = Coo()
coo.foo()
```

Here `coo.__dict__` gains the entry `{num:2}` when `self.num=2` is declared. Then inside of `Coo.__dict__`, `num` is set to 3.

`self.num` tries to look up `num` inside of `coo.__dict__` and finds it, printing 2

`Coo.num` looks up `num` inside of `Coo.__dict__` and finds it, printing 3.

As for the best way to access class variables in a member function, you should just use `Classname.varname` or `self.__class__.varname`. This guarantees that you won't end up using the instance variable with the same name. However, it is good design to have class and instance variables have different names. This way no confusion should ever occur.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification and detailed explanation.

Comment: Haha thank you for the excellent question, researching for the answer taught me a good deal about python!

Answer (score 0):

Python acts in a bit of a tricky way with class variables imo.
Taking this snippet of code as example :

```py
class a:
    var = 0

    def foo(self):
        self.my_name = [k for k,v in globals().items() if v is self][0]
        print(f'----------{self.my_name}.var adress:', id(a.var))
        print(f'self.var in {self.my_name} instance:', id(self.var))

    def change(self):
        print(f'changing self.var value to 1 in {self.my_name} instance')
        self.var = 1

b = a()
c = a()
b.foo()
c.foo()

c.change()

b.foo() 
c.foo()
```

which outputs

```
----------b.var adress: 140434476089552
self.var in b instance: 140434476089552
----------c.var adress: 140434476089552
self.var in c instance: 140434476089552
changing self.var value to 1 in c instance
----------b.var adress: 140434476089552
self.var in b instance: 140434476089552
----------c.var adress: 140434476089552
self.var in c instance: 140434476089584
```

You can see that some write operation (`self.var` = 1) in the `c` context did create a new variable (an instance variable) for c. This is something you really have to be aware of, otherwise you won't work with class variables but only uncorrelated instance variables.
Instead, you should always use `a.var`. This is also why method accessing class variables only should not have `self` as a parameter, to avoid this confusion.