# How to access a class variable in a method in python

Tags: python

Title says it all. I want to use a class variable but I keep getting a name error. What can I do to solve this?

Here's my code:

```
class a:
    var = 0

    def foo():
        print(a.var)
    foo()

b = a()
```

Here's the error code:

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: Why are you calling the method inside the class definition?

Comment: You should read carefully the class documentation. There are too many wrong things.

Comment: When you call `foo()` in your code above the class `a` isn't defined yet (because the call is within the class body ... the block hasn't been 'closed' yet so it's as if the class is still being defined).  `foo` exists at that point and can be called, but class `a` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does accessing class variables from an instance work in python? - a confusing example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145679/how-does-accessing-class-variables-from-an-instance-work-in-python-a-confusin)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```py
class a:
    var = 0

    def foo(self):
        print(self.var)

b = a()

b.foo()  # "print(b.var)" also works
```

Above code gives the following result:

```
0
```

Comment: You are actually accessing the class variable, but in a hacky way. If any write is done to `self.var` in any of your instances, it will no more point to the class variable. See my comment for more precise infos.

Comment: Eh, no way to know what OP really wants to achieve given the info they provided

Comment: I mean, the title's pretty clear

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `foo` function, the print statement should access the variable `var` by calling `self.var`, and not `a.var`. Also, the method `foo` should have a default parameter of `self`, like so:

```
def foo(self):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Python acts in a bit of a tricky way with class variables imo.
Taking this snippet of code as example :

```py
class a:
    var = 0

    def foo(self):
        self.my_name = [k for k,v in globals().items() if v is self][0]
        print(f'----------{self.my_name}.var adress:', id(a.var))
        print(f'self.var in {self.my_name} instance:', id(self.var))

    def change(self):
        print(f'changing self.var value to 1 in {self.my_name} instance')
        self.var = 1

b = a()
c = a()
b.foo()
c.foo()

c.change()

b.foo() 
c.foo()
```

which outputs

```
----------b.var adress: 140434476089552
self.var in b instance: 140434476089552
----------c.var adress: 140434476089552
self.var in c instance: 140434476089552
changing self.var value to 1 in c instance
----------b.var adress: 140434476089552
self.var in b instance: 140434476089552
----------c.var adress: 140434476089552
self.var in c instance: 140434476089584
```

You can see that some write operation (`self.var` = 1) in the `c` context did create a new variable (an instance variable) for c. This is something you really have to be aware of, otherwise you won't work with class variables but only uncorrelated instance variables.
Instead, you should always use `a.var`. This is also why method accessing class variables only should not have `self` as a parameter, to avoid this confusion.